# DirtyForms does not work on input hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

I added dirtyForms to my forms to detect any changes on one of the input fields https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="post" name="post">
    
  <input type="hidden" id="body" name="body">
  <froala-editor input="body">

  </froala-editor>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   $('form').dirtyForms();
});
```

However for input hidden seems like it doesn't add the dirty class, it only works for `input type="text"` . Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because it does not make sense when the user is not the one entering the data in the field.

You can do it yourself

SO does not allow the editor so I tested here

```
$('form').toggleClass('mydirty', e.target.textContent !== "");
```

tests the editor, it makes more sense than the input field

https://plungjan.name/SO/froala/

```js
$('form').dirtyForms({
  helpers: [{
    isDirty: function($node, index) {
      if ($node.is('form')) {
        return $node.hasClass('mydirty');
      }
    }
  }]
});

var editor = new FroalaEditor('#froala')

$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  $('form').toggleClass('mydirty', e.target.textContent !== "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.2.3/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="post" name="post">

  <input type="hidden" id="body" name="body">
  <div id="froala" input="body">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But if i remove the text entered, it will still stay dirty. Thanks for helping

Comment: @airsoftFreak See updated script. I had to test on my own server

Comment: Really appreciate your help, but the approach for this `e.target.textContent !== ""` has some drawback.

Comment: For example, if i save the `#body` from `""` to `"something"`

Comment: and if edit `"something"` to `"something new"`, it will add the mydirty as usual but if remove `"something new"` to `"something"` again, the mydirty class will persist.

Comment: but for `<input type="text" id="post" name="post">` it will work easily. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: The scenario above for `<input type="text" id="post" name="post">` is working smoothly but the solution you provided didn't work for the above scenario

Comment: That is not my experience. If I add any text to the editor, it gets dirty. If I remove the text, the dirty is removed too

Comment: Go to https://plungjan.name/SO/froala/, click the horizontal line to get the editor started. Type some text. Try to leave the page. Dirtify will alert. Click cancel and delete the text in the editor. Now you may leave the page